# Ensure order of async operations

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I'm looking for a pattern that can be used in JavaScript to ensure that the results of certain async callbacks are processed in a certain order. I can think of ways to do this, but not of elegant ones, so I'd appreciate JavaScripty ways of achieving this.

The immediate use-case is that I receive events from an EventEmitter that I need to handle. I handle them by either:

1. Immediately performing a DB operation
2. First performing a HTTP request and then performing a DB operation

And I have the constraint, that the DB operations must be performed in the same order as the corresponding events that I receive from the EventEmitter.

Because the HTTP request is async, it can happen that the corresponding DB operation is overtaken by a new event that does not need to perform a HTTP request and can perform the DB operation immediately.

But I can also imagine this happening with more deeply nested async call hierarchies...

**Example:**

```
let events = require('events');

let emitter = new events.EventEmitter();
emitter.on('event', (count) => {
    if (count % 2) {
        immediateDBOperation(count);
    } else {
        asyncHTTPOperation(count, () => immediateDBOperation(count));
    }
});

function immediateDBOperation(count) {
    // Need to be processed in correct order
    console.log(count);
}

function asyncHTTPOperation(count, callback) {
    setTimeout(() => callback(count, 'foo'), 1500);
}

let count = 0;
setInterval(() => emitter.emit('event', count++), 1000);
```

**Output:**

```
1
0
3
2
...
```

Comment: You need a lock system. Can be a field in your database, or a variable telling if there is an unfinished action still waiting.